# Target velocity on bullet physic (python interface)

Tags: python, physics, velocity, bullet

I'm new to Bullet. I'm using pybullet and want to make a car.
I'm using [this standard URDF-model](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/data/racecar/racecar.urdf) for modelling the car.

I want my car to go, for example, at a speed of 20 in the straight direction.
I can write:

```
p.resetBaseVelocity(car, [20, 0, 0])
```

and everything will work.

This code:

```
linearVelocity, angularVelocity = p.getBaseVelocity (car)
print(linearVelocity)
```

will output `(20, 0, 0)`. But of course, I want to achieve this effect with the help of wheels, using `setJointMotorControl2`, `VELOCITY_CONTROL`, and `targetVelocity`. I saw [this example racecar](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/examples/racecar.py) and I tried it to run this machine on an infinite plane as in the example, But the linear velocity that I managed to achieve is about `(1.0, 0, 0)`, and I want `linearVelocity (20, 0, 0)`. I tried to change the code in the URDF model:

```
<Limit effort = "10" velocity = "100" />
```

I set it to very high values ​​and made the target velocity very large but there was no effect. How can I change the URDF model or give, please, a simple example of a model that can travel at high speeds.

I can of course do it artificially with:

```
 linearVelocity = [x * 2 for x in linearVelocity]
 p.resetBaseVelocity (my_car, linearVelocity)
```

But it's not beautiful, I want do this with the target velocity of the wheels. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The limit and effort fields in a URDF file are not processed by pybullet.

You can modify the targetVelocity (for the wheels) in that racecar example to go faster.